# execute javascript from textarea

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, textarea

I'm not entirely sure if this is possible, but I'm trying to create a mini faux editor in a browser that runs javascript on the page. Here's what I've been trying to do in theory

HTML

```
​<textarea id="cnsl"></textarea>
<button onclick="run()"> run </button>
```

javascript

```
var cnsl = document.getElementById('cnsl');

function run() {
    return cnsl.value
}
```

more specifically I'm trying to write to a canvas element via the 'code' I type into the text area, so that if, for example, i type ctx.fillRect(10,10,10,10); into my textarea and then execute that run() function the 10x10 square will appear in my canvas.

I had a little luck when instead of returning the cnsl.value I wrote it to the innerHTML of an empty script element in my HTML. But this would only work the first time I'd execute the function and then won't work again until I refresh the page. (for example this: http://jsfiddle.net/ur5KC/1/ which doesn't seem to work on jsfiddle but works locally as I described above)

...any ideas??? thnx in advance!

Comment: **eval** function will help you: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.ASP

Comment: ...though a better link would be https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create a script element, set its [text](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#dom-script-text) (or [textContent](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#textcontent) if HTML5 and DOM 3 compatible) to the script to execute, then insert it in the document. Best to remove elements as you go so you don't end up with a large number of (useless) script elements.

```js
function run() {
    var el = document.getElementById('cnsl');
    var scriptText = el.value;
    var oldScript = document.getElementById('scriptContainer');
    var newScript;

    if (oldScript) {
      oldScript.parentNode.removeChild(oldScript);
    }

    newScript = document.createElement('script');
    newScript.id = 'scriptContainer';
    newScript.text = el.value;
    document.body.appendChild(newScript);
}
```

```html
<textarea id="cnsl"></textarea>
<button onclick="run();">run</button>
```

Note that you must create a new element because in HTML5, each [script element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#the-script-element) has an associated flag to indicate whether it's been executed and it can only be executed once. Replacing the content doesn't reset the flag, and a cloned script element keeps the setting of the element it was cloned from.

Encouraging a user to execute their own scripts may destroy the document, but that's your problem I guess. :-)

An alternative is to simply [`eval`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.2) whatever they enter, it's more or less equivalent to the above (but a lot less code):

```js
function run() {
  var el = document.getElementById('cnsl');
  el && eval(el.value);
}
```

```html
<textarea id="cnsl"></textarea>
<button onclick="run();">run</button>
```

Comment: ++ for the first method. It can be modified to work for many different scenarios; I used some similar code to execute user-written JavaScript inside an iframe. I did it a little differently, though - I had a separate div with id="script", and I put the script elements inside the div. To prevent script element accumulation, I only had to wipe out the innerHTML of the div every time I appended a new script.

Comment: Too risky. You just can't execute whatever code your user types in a input field without any sanitazion; script injection is always a big risk if your site is heavy JS dependant.

Comment: @FranVerona—users can already run whatever script they want in a web page, this doesn't expose any new weakness. If your web app can't handle that, it has some issues.

Answer (score 6):

Thnx @Prodigy && @JayC !!!

such a simple solution, I did not know such a function existed :)

using the eval() function did the trick!!!

```js
var cnsl = document.getElementById('cnsl');

function run() {    
    return eval(cnsl.value); // << did the trick ;)
}

//canvas
var ctx;

function setup() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
}
setup();
```

```html
<textarea cols=50 id="cnsl">
ctx.fillRect(10,10,10,10);
</textarea>
<button onclick="run()"> run </button>
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hey people of the year 2020 and later.. it should be noted that `eval()` is potentially dangerous to use.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work in JavaScript but it works in other languages, try importing your script into the script that has the text area then when you want to do the action in the text area call the method in the imported script that has the code you want to execute