# Executing code from a text area

Tags: javascript

I have a page that accepts Javascript code in a text area. I would like to run that code when the user presses the run button.

Is the following possible:

```
var programFunction = new Function(document.getElementById('program').value);

<button type="button" onclick="programFunction">run</button>
```

Let's say the textarea program has the following in it:

```
document.getElementById('program').value = 'Tested';
```

When I try to test this myself, I don't get any errors but I also don't get any output.

Comment: `onclick="programFunction()"` works as long as `programFunction` is global.  You forgot the `()` in your `onclick` attribute.

Comment: possible duplicate of [execute javascript from textarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243563/execute-javascript-from-textarea)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need your "run" button to process and run the code.

At its simplest, it's just:

```
onclick="eval(document.getElementById('program').value);"
```

Note that in this case, `eval` is perfectly okay *provided* that the value of the program field can only come from the user's own input, and not anyone else's.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things wrong in your code:

- It seems like you try to access the content of the textarea before it got a value.
- You don't run the function you created.

You have to retrieve the value of the texarea when the button is pressed, not before. Still using `Function`, it would look like:

```
<script>
function runCode() {
    var source = document.getElementById('program').value;
    var func = new Function(source);
    func();
}
</script>
<button type="button" onclick="runCode()">run</button>
```