# Editor HTML and CSS in Real Time that execute JAVASCRIPT too

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, editor

I did a script that help me to make a web page in realtime, I can put html and css and everything work well, but I can't execute javascript because I am using a editor based in string, can you help me to find a way to execute javascript in this editor?

Pay attention, with this simple script you can put a whole page's code with CSS and HTML without escape and you'll see a formated page, but JAVASCRIPT don't work in this script.

```js
function html() {
var str = document.getElementById("go").value;
  document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = str;   
}
```

```html
<p id="show"></p>
<textarea id="go" onKeyUp="html()"  width="100%" cols="50" rows="10">
   </textarea>
```

UPDATE, at last, I got, this editor execute javascript too! Now I can build a whole page with javascript inside,  thank you for the answers!!!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#editor').keyup(function(){
      $('#page').html($(this).val());
  });
   });
```

```html
<p id="page"></p>
 <textarea id="editor"  width="100%" cols="50" rows="10" placeholder="you can use html, css and javascript here..."></textarea>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [execute javascript from textarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243563/execute-javascript-from-textarea)

Comment: You can execute JavaScript using the `eval` method. 
Btw you have to pay attention that you pass to eval really only JavaScript code, and your HTML example is bugging when you provide angular brackets, you can see them in the rendering when you type the first `<`

Comment: Have you tried using codepen? You can build out whole projects in it and it continuously executes html/css/js

Comment: Yes, but now I don't need internet to do it, for the other hand, I would like to have a script like that!

Answer (score 0):

You are adding everything in a paragraph tag. That is why nothing in script tags are working. You might want to append everything in the body tag:

```
function html() {
  var str = document.getElementById("go").value;
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML = str;   
}
```

Can you clarify what you mean by "find a way to execute javascript in this editor?" What are you desired results?

Comment: wrong. His question is why he cannot execute JavaScript and In order to execute JavaScript he needs to eval the code that he passes in

Comment: @quirimmo If you check his code you can clearly see no JavaScript is going to execute in a paragraph tag.

Comment: Ok I do paste here "can you help me to find a way to execute javascript in this editor?"

Comment: I am not saying that your JavaScript is not good, and I didn't mention his, your or my JavaScript. I just outlined that his question is why JavasScript is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript won't run automatically like that, u need eval() to run it, I would suggest something like this:

Although it increases the security risk but it is one of the only ways to do it.

```js
function html1() {
var str1 = document.getElementById("go1").value;
  document.getElementById("show1").innerHTML = str1;   
}

function html2() {
var str2 = document.getElementById("go2").value;
  document.getElementById("show2").innerHTML = eval(str2);   
}
```

```html
<p id="show1"></p>
<p id="show2"></p>
<textarea id="go1" onKeyUp="html1()"  width="100%" cols="50" rows="10"> </textarea>
<textarea id="go2" width="100%" cols="50" rows="10"> </textarea>
<br><button onclick="html2()">Try it</button>
```